# is LRU fully associative cache the same as a queue sorted by which is used most recently?

Tags: cpu-architecture

I might be overthinking this but in the scenario where you have cache with size 3 and addresses 1 2 3 4 are called will the cache look like this:
1 -> 2 1 -> 3 2 1 -> 4 3 2 shifting physically every block to the right or like this
1 -> 1 2 -> 1 2 3 -> 4 2 3 keeping track of the least recently used like a cyclic array

I imagine the second scenario still needs shifting on hits, given addresses 1 2 3 1 it would like this 1 -> 1 2 -> 1 2 3 -> 2 3 1

Comment: Yes, but a problem with LRU is that it is hard to implement in hardware when the cache has high associativity, so [approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies#LRU_approximations) are often used.